# How to insert elements into a sheet from list A based on list B values?

Tags: python

Ive 2 lists one is the values(List A) i want to insert into an excel sheet, the other one(List B) is the amount of time i need the same value from that position to be inserted, their length will be always equal. Example:

```
#Lists(both lists length are gonna be equal to each other)
 A =['a','foo','John','element','tryme','test','test2']
 B =[2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]
```

How they gotta be displayed in the excel sheet:

[image]

As displayed above, the list 1 indicates the amount of times each element is gonna be inserted(A[0] inserted 2 times, and so goes on). So far ive tried to create a dictionary , but after that ive no clue how to do the insert and also im not sure if im in the way:

```
res = {A[i]: B[i] for i in range(len(A))}
```

**PS: If u need more info please ask, im new to python but im loving it, but sadly ive none besides the internet who can provide me help or ask questions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can be achieved using:

```py
C = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    for _ in range(B[i]):
        C.append(A[i])

print(C)
# ['a', 'a', 'foo', 'foo', 'John', 'element', 'tryme', 'tryme', 'tryme', 'test', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2']
```

or as a one liner:

```py
C = [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) for _ in range(B[i])]
```

Comment: whats the trick behind the underscore?

Comment: Underscores are often used to indicate a variable that won't be used. You will often find them when unpacking a tuple and there are certain values you don't need or care about, so you assign them to an underscore to indicate you won't be using it in the future